# rewrite condition on same domain but with same query string

Tags: .htaccess

So I'm trying to write a really simple rewrite condition in my .htaccess but I'm a very beginner with it and I can't seem to make it work.
I'm trying to redirect from `example.com/me/name` to `example.com/me?n=name` 
I've read other people's posts, instructions, tutorials, I can't understand where I'm wrong.
What I tried is this:

```
RewriteRule (http://example.com/me/*) http://example.com/me?n=*
```

But it doesn't do anything different.

Answer (score 0):

You can not match against `host/domain` in Rule's pattern, to rewrite `/me/name` to `/me?n=name` you can use the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^me/((?!index).+)/?$ /me?n=$1 [L]
```